# Is there a way to use gcc as a library?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Anyone knows a solution that works something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gcc.h> /* This .h is what I'm looking for. */

int main (void) {
    /* variables declaration (...) */

    /* The following line is supposed to be equivalent to:
     *     $ gcc main.c -o main */
    results = gcc_compile_and_link("main.c", "main");

    /* Now I want to use the warnings and errors to do something.
     * For instance, I'll print them to the console: */
    printf("warnings:\n");
    for (i=0; i<results.warns_len; i++)
        printf("%s\n", results.warings[i].msg);
    printf("errors\n");
    for (i=0; i<results.errs_len; i++)
        printf("%s\n", results.errors[i].msg);

    /* free memory and finalize (...) */
    return 0;
}
```

I know I can run the command "gcc main.c -o main" in a fork and parse the output... but I was looking for something more '*reliable*' like the example above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GCC was explicitly designed to resist being used as a tools base/library. You need to use Clang for this, or call GCC through commandline.

Comment: Do you know the reason for that design decision?

Comment: `libgccjit` is working in that direction, although it will be an uphill battle: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/323821/124651

Comment: I recall this being the case as well but I'm having trouble finding an original source for it

Answer (score 7):

**libgccjit**

Introduced in GCC 5 and is still experimental as of GCC 6.

Docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/

Related questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144793/gcc-for-parsing-code
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735360/compiling-program-within-another-program-using-gcc

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible with gcc but you might find [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/) (an embeddable C compiler) good enough for what you have in mind. The distribution comes with a libtcc library that allows to compile, link and run C code "on the fly".

Note that this only for C, your question is also tagged C++ but I've not seen any equivalent of tcc for C++.

Comment: Notice that `tcc` compiles quickly, but is not optimizing at all. The generated code is often 3 to 10 times slower than what `gcc -O2` would produce.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>(I am guessing you are on some POSIX system, like Linux or MacOSX)</sup>

You obviously should look into [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), as [mentioned by Ciro Santilli](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/323821/40065). You'll then build some [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)-like representation of the generated code. Of course you might consider [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) instead, or even some simpler [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library like [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/) or [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) (but `libjit` and `lightning` are emitting code quickly, but the emitted code is slow and unoptimized).

However, you might still consider [emitting some C code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) in a temporary file and forking a compilation of it (e.g. as shared library that you would later dynamically load as a plugin using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) & [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)), see [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/289379/40065) & [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/303123/40065) for details.

Notice an important fact: generating [optimized code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) takes CPU time (with GCCJIT, or LLVM, or by running `gcc -O2`) because it is a difficult task. So the overhead of forking a `gcc` process (or using some other compiler, like `clang`) is negligible (w.r.t. using some library like GCCJIT or LLVM).

Actually, my experience (in [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)) is that on current desktops and laptops, emitting a few hundred lines of C code and forking a compilation of them is fast enough (one or two tenth of seconds) to be compatible with user interaction. So today, you could consider having a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) which would do that. See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) related answer.

Look also into [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) and [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) which is an implementation which compiles into machine code at every REPL interaction.

NB: Seeking partners interested by [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there's anything better than forking gcc. You might consider clang, which is more designed for this kind of use.

Answer (score 1):

You should obviously look at clang. Compiling code at runtime was a design goal for clang. For example, Apple uses clang to compile OpenGL, OpenCL, Metal, JavaScript.

Gcc on the other hand had the explicit goal of not allowing this (which is why Xcode doesn’t use gcc for many years).