# Copy a function in memory to a different location and be able to run it from the new location

Tags: c++, memory-usage, reverse-engineering

How'd I go about copying a function in memory to a different location and be able to run it from the new location in C++?

I thought maybe memcmp would work, but I'm not sure how I'd go about running it after it copied to the new location.

Comment: **Why do you ask?** What is the the usage scenario?

Comment: BTW, the *reverse-engineering* tag is inappropriate.

Comment: Without additional motivation (so you should **edit your question** to *improve it*) I am tempted to vote for close (or downvote) the question.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do that (copying the code of some function) in a portable way. The [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) of some function cannot be moved without care, because in many [instruction sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) the code depends of its position. For example, many `CALL` or `JUMP` machine instructions are relative to the program counter (so if you "move" them they will jump to an erroneous location). Details are implementation specific and vary with the compiler, the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), the [instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set), the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). Read more about [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29), e.g. Levine's [Linkers & loaders](http://iecc.com/linkers/) book.

> I thought maybe `memcpy`  would work

No, it generally won't. (BTW `memcmp` is just comparing bytes, not "moving" or "copying" them).

Read about [Position Independent Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) and [Relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29) (& [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space))

Perhaps you should consider generating machine code, using some [JIT compilation library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) like [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), or [GNU libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), or [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit), or [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/). On POSIX systems, you could simply emit some C or C++ code into some temporary file, compile it (into a position independent shared object), and use [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) & [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) (see [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/289379/40065) for more).

> but I'm not sure how I'd go about running it after it copied to the new location

If the new location contains *valid* executable machine code (but see [W^X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX)), you just use some function pointer (and call it). But beware of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

PS. You really should *motivate* your question, which looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: When you say "Beware of undefined behaviour", you mean, "The whole thing is undefined behaviour from start to finish and you're absolutely dependent on behaviour your implementation happens to define", right? You make it sound like if he slips up it'll be UB.

Comment: I was more precisely thinking of calling (thru a function pointer) some "wrong" machine code (e.g. like some `memcpy`-ed one)